# WPF memory "leak" in x64

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, 64-bit

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?  I don't think this is normal behavior and the GC is obviously doing something.  This is a completely blank WPF project compiled under "AnyCPU" vs "x64" as platform target.  I'm trying to use C++/CLI with WPF which can't be compiled to "AnyCPU" - however, when I use x64 as a platform target with WPF - simply resizing the window will cause the process to expand (on my computer) to upwards of 10GB of memory.

This is a completely blank project.  The only thing I've done is change the platform target, entered debugging mode, and constantly resized the window back and forth:

[image]

If anyone knows how to make a WPF project targeting x64 and whether or not I'm just stupid and there's some reason you can't do that, I'd love to know.

PS: I'm on Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2015

EDIT: confirmed this "leak" also exists in a "published" project so it's not just some sort of artifact of interfacing WPF x64 with 32 bit Visual Studio.

If anyone can reproduce this, it would be nice to know.

Comment: On my work computer (Windows 7) the memory usage does not increase when resizing the window using the `x64` platform. When you use the `AnyCPU` platform the default is to "prefer 32 bit" which means that what you see is a difference between 32 and 64 bit. `AnyCPU` is really only useful for managed library projects where the same library can be used in both 32 and 64 bit processes.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Sigh... I wonder if it's Windows 10 or something wrong with my computer specifically.  I really prefer working on my projects in x64, but I guess I can switch it to x86.  Like I said, since I'm including a C++/CLI dll it won't let me do "AnyCPU" without throwing an error.

Comment: `AnyCPU` indicates that the assembly can execute in both a 32 and 64 bit process. This is possible with managed code because of the the Just In Time compilation. C++/CLI enables you to include unmanged code in your managed assembly so it will always be either 32 or 64 bit and never both, e.g. no `AnyCPU` possibility. Unless you are building a reusable library your code will deterministically execute as either 32 or 64 bit depending on the settings of your `.exe` project as long as you are on a 64 bit OS. In that case `AnyCPU` does not provide any advantage to you.